# How to display image from current working directory in Python

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, qt-designer, qlabel

I would like to display an image using multiple label in a GUI(Qt Designer). The image file should be grab from current working directory and display on it own label upon user press Push Button.

Image can be displayed in label_2 when i hardcoded the image directory path but not for label_1.

```
  def capture_image(self):

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    print('Execute_captureImage')

    i = 1
    while i <= int(self.qty_selected):
        # while i < 2:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        cv2.imshow('Please review image before capture', frame)

        if not ret:
            break
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)

        if k % 256 == 27:
            # ESC pressed
            print("Escape hit, closing...")
            break
        if k % 256 == 32:
            # SPACE pressed
            self.img_name = self.lotId + '_{}.jpeg'.format(i)
            path = 'c:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\Testing' + '\\' + self.lotId + '\\' + self.img_name
            print('CurrentImage = ' + path)

            if not os.path.exists(path):
                print('Not yet exist')
                cv2.imwrite(
                    os.path.join('c:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\Testing' + '\\' + self.lotId,
                                 self.img_name),
                    frame)
                print("{}".format(self.img_name))
                # i += 1
                break

            else:
                print('Image already exist')
                i += 1

    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()



  def display_image(self):

       label_vid01 = 'c:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\Testing' + '\\' + self.lotId + '\\' + self.img_name
       label_vid02 = 'c:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\Testing' + '\\' + self.lotId + '\\' + self.img_name
       # label_vid03 = 'c:/Users/Desktop/Python/Image/image3.jpg'
       self.label_vid01.setScaledContents(True)
       self.label_vid02.setScaledContents(True)
       self.label_vid03.setScaledContents(True)
       self.label_vid01.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(label_vid01))
       self.label_vid02.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(label_vid02))
       print(repr(label_vid01))
       print(os.path.exists(label_vid01))
```

May i know where is the mistake?

'self.lotId' is input text based on user input.

[label snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXEtw.jpg)

Comment: What is the output of `print(repr(label_1))`? And what is the output of `print(os.path.exists(label_1))`?

Comment: I have edited the path for label_1 and output for print(repr(label_1)) is 'c:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\Testing\\ABCDE\\ABCDE_2.jpeg'.                  And for print(os.path.exists(label_1) output is 'True'. The problem now is how to display next following image on label_2?

Comment: Show the code for the function where you are setting the image on the label.

Comment: Already update the code for function capture image and display image in my question including snapshot of the label.

Comment: Check the pixmap: `p = QtGui.QPixmap(); print(p.load(label_vid01)); print(p.isNull()); print(p.size())`.

Comment: that doesn't solve my current problem. Below is output :                            print(p.load(label_vid01)) ---- True;
print(p.isNull()) --- False;
print(p.size()) --- PyQt4.QtCore.QSize(1280, 960)

Comment: Please try the script in my answer below. I suggest you try it first with some "normal" images (i.e. not from cv2 video capture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo script below works for me on Windows XP. If this also works for you, the problem must be in the `capture_image` function in your example (which I cannot test at the moment).

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.viewer = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.viewer.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode)
        self.viewer.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.viewer.setResizeMode(QtGui.QListView.Adjust)
        self.viewer.setSpacing(10)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        self.viewer.clear()
        name = self.edit.text()
        for index in range(3):
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
            path = r'E:\Python\Testing\%s\%s_%d.jpg' % (name, name, index + 1)
            print('load (%s) %r' % (pixmap.load(path), path))
            item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(os.path.basename(path))
            item.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(path))
            self.viewer.addItem(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 150, 650, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This demo script is work perfectly when tested. Let me clarify. Image that i have multiple images i.e 3 pcs with different file naming (A_1.jpeg,A_2.jpeg,A_3.jpeg) and i need to display in 3 different labels respectively. How to grab the image from directory and display without user interaction?

Comment: @faizal_a. I have updated my code example. The sub-directory and file-name prefix are taken from the line-edit. So if you enter "ABC", the files will be "ABC/ABC_1.jpg", etc.

Comment: That is what i'm looking for. Great demo!. But, how could i display in grid view(5x5) with proper label? i'm almost complete my project and this is a last part that i'm got stuck since 1 week ago.

Comment: @faizal_a. I have converted my example to use a list-view. PS: if you found my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it.

Comment: What is the best method if I want to display it in a new tab?

Comment: @faizal_a. Please post a new question.